# How to keep track of last successful run in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, etl

I am running an ETL script that loads data from mysql into teradata. The script aims to select all rows later than the timestamp of the last successful run of the bash script. Since I do not have write access to the mysql database, I need to store the last run timestamp with the bash script. Is there an easy way to store the timestamp of a successful run? I was thinking I could have a file that I would touch at the end of the script and then check its mtime, or just parse out the timestamp from a log file. What are some better strategies to do this?

Comment: I think, timestamp is the simpliest date format to handle with bash. It could be converted in any form with `date --date='@2147483647'` . Not sure if I have understood your question right.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with Teradata?

Comment: i guess not, i'll remove the tag

Comment: I reworded the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your script, use `set -e`[1](http://ss64.com/bash/set.html) so that the script exits immediately if any command within the script fails. Then, at the end, log successful completion with a unix timestamp `date +%s`.

You can then use `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(<YOUR TIMESTAMP>, <YOUR MYSQL DATE FORMAT>)`[2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to pull rows that are newer than the last successful completion.

One big caveat: I would not rely solely on timestamps to approach this problem. I would pull from MySQL with some time overlap and check primary keys for each insert into teradata to avoid inserting duplicates. To follow this approach, just subtract 1800 from `<YOUR TIMESTAMP>` to ensure a 30 minute overlap.